# Apache Spark Mllib 2.1.0 with Scala sbt error

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark-mllib

My small apache spark project with Scala was working fine till i added Mllib.

My sbt built file looks like below but with that i am getting compilation error. Can't i build Apache Spark Mllib with Scala 2.11.X ? Any pointers will be helpful.

```
error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file::
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-launcher _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-sketch _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-ast _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.scalatest:scalatest _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.twitter:chill _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-sql _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-jackson _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-core _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-tags _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-core _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-network-common _2.11, _2.10
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.apache.spark:spark-launcher, org.apache.spark:spark-sketch, org.json4s:json4s-ast, org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst, org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle, org.scalatest:scalatest, com.twitter:chill, org.apache.spark:spark-sql, org.json4s:json4s-jackson, com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala, org.json4s:json4s-core, org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe, org.apache.spark:spark-tags, org.apache.spark:spark-core, org.apache.spark:spark-network-common
[error] Total time: 18 s, completed 10-Mar-2017 20:41:51


version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test"
//libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.5.0"
//libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.10
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "2.1.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely build Apache Spark MLlib with Scala 2.11.X. For that you have to change the library dependency for Spark MLlib from:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "2.1.0"
```

to

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.1.0"
```

or

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.0"
```

Comment: Thanks @himanshullltian. I tried the last option but that didn't work. Let me try the first option.